# why does Wikipedia's perceptron correctly separate XOR?

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

I understand a perceptron can only work correctly on linearly separable sets, like the outputs of the NAND, AND, OR functions. I've been reading [Wikipedia's entry on the perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), and got to play with its code.

XOR is a case where a single layer perceptron should fail, as it's not a linearly separable set.

```
#xor
print ("xor")
t_s           = [((1, 1, 1), 0), ((1, 0, 1), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 1), 0)] 


threshold     = 0.5
learning_rate = 0.1
w             = [0, 0, 0]

def dot_product(values, weights):
    return sum(value * weight for value, weight in zip(values, weights))

def train_perceptron(threshold, learning_rate, weights, training_set):
    while True:
        #print('-' * 60)
        error_count = 0

        for input_vector, desired_output in training_set:
            #print(weights)
            result = dot_product(input_vector, weights) > threshold
            error  = desired_output - result

            if error != 0:
                error_count += 1
                for index, value in enumerate(input_vector):
                    weights[index] += learning_rate * error * value

        if error_count == 0: #iterate till there's no error 
            break
    return training_set

t_s = train_perceptron(threshold, learning_rate, w, t_s)

t_s = [(a[1:], b) for a, b in t_s]

for a, b in t_s:
    print "input: " + str(a) + ", output: " + str(b)
```

[The output for this Ideone run is correct for XOR](http://ideone.com/kdypyJ). How come?

```
xor
input: (1, 1), output: 0
input: (0, 1), output: 1
input: (1, 0), output: 1
input: (1, 1), output: 0
```

Comment: Your training set seems incorrect. The last input should be, (0,0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You input `t_s` into `train_perceptron` and return it without modifying. Then you output it. Of course that works perfectly....

```
t_s = train_perceptron(threshold, learning_rate, w, t_s)
```

This does not change `t_s` at all. `train_perceptron` does at no point modify `training_set`,. but returns it: `return training_set`

Then here you output it:

```
t_s = [(a[1:], b) for a, b in t_s]

for a, b in t_s:
    print "input: " + str(a) + ", output: " + str(b)
```

Comment: It's worthwhile noting that the original Wikipedia code isn't even in a function; it's not intended to modify `t_s` (which wouldn't have made much sense).  It's modifying `weights` in-place.

Comment: duh, you're right, it's the modified weights what I should output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your training set:

```
t_s = [((1, 1, 1), 0), ((1, 0, 1), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((0, 0, 0), 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If my memory is correct to break non-linear problem with a perceptron you need at least one hidden layer with non-linear activation for neurons in this layer.